# What is the point of making a class generic?

Tags: java, class, generics

when you have a method, I understand that it makes sense to declare it generic so that i can take generic arguments. Like this:

```
public <T> void function(T element) {
    // Some code...
}
```

But what exactly is the idea behind making a whole class generic if I can simply declare every method generic?

Comment: So you can have variables in the class of a generic type?

Comment: A method is a member and it can be generic without making the whole class generic. The only other thing I could think of is being able to make instance variables generic

Comment: I think this shouldn't be downvoted without explanation. While most of us that use Java for some amount of time may think this is obvious, there are people out there who just started to learn, and I think this is a valid question.

Comment: actually, that function above can be equivalently written as `public void function(Object element)`. the generics is not useful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the difference is if you try to make each method in your class generic the generic type you'd use in your say firstGenericMethod may or may not be the same type.What i mean is.

```
public <T> void firstGenMethod(...){

}

public <T> void secondGenMethod(...){

}
```

**Test:**

```
  SomeClass ref = new SomeClass();
  ref.firstGenMethod("string");
  ref.secondGenMethod(123);//legal as this generic type is not related to the generic type which is used by firstGenMethod
```

In the above case there is no gaurentee that both the methods have the same generic type.It depends on how you invoke them. If you make the class generic though, the type is applied to all the methods inside that class.

```
class Test<T>{

    public void firstGenMethod(T t){

    }

    public  void secondGenMethod(T t){

    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
 Test<String> testingString = new Test<>();
   testingString.firstGenMethod("abc");
   testingString.firstGenMethod(123);// invalid as your Test class only expects String in this case
```

You'd usually make your class generic where you'd want the entire behaviour(methods) of that class to process on the same type. best examples are class's in **Java Collection Framework**

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the Collection classes. Take `List<T>` as an example. If the class weren't declared generic, how would you make sure that only elements of the correct class could be inserted into the list? And how would you know what you get when calling `ArrayList.get(i)`?

Answer (score 2):

Precisely, to enfore that all the methods in this class apply to a certain type.

This is typically used in "containers" classes. If you're building a List, and you make it generic, you want to be sure that adding element, getting element, iterating, etc... always uses the same type.

As you mention, this also allows you to use instance variables of a certain type, and have several methods use this instance (maybe returning it, affect it...) in a coherent way.

If you have a class that is "generic" with several different types, it might be a sign that you're really writing two generic classes in one... (although this can be a legitimate thing.)

Answer (score 1):

The main idea is to bound the class/method for a type.The best example is the concept of `Generics` in programming language.It is the real application of polymorphism
Generic classes encapsulate operations that are not specific to a particular data type. The most common use for generic classes is with collections like linked lists, hash tables, stacks, queues, trees and so on where operations such as adding and removing items from the collection are performed in much the same way regardless of the type of data being stored.

For most scenarios requiring collection classes, the recommended approach is to use the ones provided in the programming languages.
Reffering from [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)
**A generic type is a generic class or interface that is parameterized over types**

```
public class Box {
    private Object object;

    public void set(Object object) { this.object = object; }
    public Object get() { return object; }
}
```

By generically you can strict it to

```
public class Box<T> {
    // T stands for "Type"
    private T t;

    public void set(T t) { this.t = t; }
    public T get() { return t; }
}
```

I also suggest you to see this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm)