# Making class Generic in java

Tags: java, collections

```
 public class ClassGenericParameterized<T> {

    public void add(T t1, T t2){
        //System.out.println(t1+t2);
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(t1.toString()) + Integer.parseInt(t2.toString()));          
    }

    public void multiply(T t1, T t2){
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(t1.toString()) * Integer.parseInt(t2.toString()));          
    }

    public void subtract(T t1, T t2){
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(t1.toString()) - Integer.parseInt(t2.toString()));          
    }

    public void division(T t1, T t2){
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(t1.toString()) / Integer.parseInt(t2.toString()));          
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ClassGenericParameterized<Integer> ob = new ClassGenericParameterized<Integer>();
        ob.add(1,2);
        ob.multiply(2, 4);
        ob.subtract(15, 6);
        ob.division(6, 3);

    }
}
```

What is the logic and need of making the class Generic in java
when replace the statement

```
 ClassGenericParameterized<Integer> ob = new ClassGenericParameterized<Integer>()
```

by

```
ClassGenericParameterized<Double> ob = new ClassGenericParameterized<Double>()
```

gives

```
Error(The method add(Double, Double) in the type ClassGenericParameterized<Double> is not applicable for the arguments (int, int))
```

As my thinking it is because of the statement written as inside the add method as `Integer.parseInt(t1.toString()) + Integer.parseInt(t2.toString())`

so again tried to replace the statement

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(t1.toString()) + Integer.parseInt(t2.toString()));
```

by

```
System.out.println(t1+t2)
```

which gives

```
Error(The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) T, T).
```

Then how could this made to be generic in real sense ? Could someone please explain why it is happening and how to rectify this error to implement my functionality?

Comment: The problem is that `int` cannot be autoboxed to `Double`.

Comment: And you're totally misunderstanding generics, since the actual type of `T` has no meaning inside your methods.

Comment: Yes  that i already guessed, what is the way to correct it ? @sotirios

Comment: the autoboxing doesn't work in your case, try this:  `ob.add((double)1,(double)2);`

Comment: What do you want to do? There is no *generic* way to do add() like that.

Comment: @Andreas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022819/what-is-the-point-of-making-a-class-generic

Comment: I meant that the numeric `+` operator (as opposed to string concatenation) is a compile-time construct that works on specific *primitive* types.

Comment: I was learning Generic Classes, so tried with it , In this context only if you can tell about generic class ? @Andreas

Comment: If you're asking "what's the point of generics", maybe you should read your book again. Try googling that quoted text and you'll find lots of good reading.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, generics would not be a good fit.  The reason:

- You cannot simply declare any type capable of addition, subtraction, multiplication, or division.  `T` has an upper bound of `Object`.
- If you set the bound to `<T extends Number>`, this still wouldn't work, since you couldn't guarantee that you could autobox whatever you wanted in that parameter to the type `T` the class was bound to.

Ultimately, you're going to want to look at using `Number` instead as your parameter.  Since `Number` is the parent class of all numerical wrappers including `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal`, you can leverage that instead.

```
public class NumberOperations {

    public void add(Number t1, Number t2){
        //System.out.println(t1+t2);
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(t1.toString()) + Integer.parseInt(t2.toString()));
    }

    public void multiply(Number t1, Number t2){
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(t1.toString()) * Integer.parseInt(t2.toString()));
    }

    public void subtract(Number t1, Number t2){
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(t1.toString()) - Integer.parseInt(t2.toString()));
    }

    public void division(Number t1, Number t2){
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(t1.toString()) / Integer.parseInt(t2.toString()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NumberOperations ob = new NumberOperations();
        ob.add(1, 2);
        ob.multiply(2, 4);
        ob.subtract(15, 6);
        ob.division(6, 3);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little of theory first:

Generics in Java (and other languages) is a language technique oriented to use the same program to process fully disjoint types.

The most common example are the `Collection` containers: Any Collection stores objects of "any" parameter type, which is unknown at compile time but will be always the same at runtime. For example:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    private T[] array;
    public void set(T t) {...}
    public T get() {...}
    public T[] get2() {...}
    public Set<T> get3() {...}
}
```

When compiling this class, we don't know what will be T. But with this client program:

```
MyClass<String> obj=new MyClass<String>();
```

... We will have an object of `MyClass` which will be bounded always to `String`: Every ocurrence of `T` will be filled with `String`.

If you want to ensure some hierarchy constraint in your generic class, you can require that the parameter type has a minimal superclass like this:

```
public class MyClass<T extends SomeOtherClass>
```

Now, let's go to the practical problem:

- Your abstraction is well designed but wrongly used: In the `main` method, you are suplying `int` values. That's okay for `Integer` type parameter, but be careful: If you change to `Double` type parameter, *you must* also change the values provided as input parameters for the methods.
- Altough is well designed, it is not correctly implemented: The way you convert the T values to integers is poor: One client program could declare:

  `ClassGenericParameterized<String> s=new ClassGenericParameterized<String>();
  s.add("hello", "world");`

... and the compiler would pass it as OK, but at runtime you will get a `NumberFormatException`, which *is not want you want*.

Think of it: If you want to code an abstraction that is oriented only to numeric values, you should rely on the compiler to check that only numeric types are provided as type parameters: Make T extend `Number`:

```
public class MyClass<T extends Number>
```

... and in this way, you could take advantage of the `intValue()` method to convert them to ints. And, most important, you won't need to use insecure parse* methods which could throw unpredictable exceptions at runtime.

Comment: thankyou @Little Santi, great explaination... tnx alot

Comment: but finally i need t1.intValue(), which again not applicable for double etc, that rip my generic ness of class

Comment: No, not at all: You can legally invoke `intValue` on any subclass of Number: Integer, Double, Long, Float, etc. And it will work OK.